# SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Don't know what to do

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I've been trying to get a fix and can't find why the error keeps appearing. Can somebody help me please?
Here is the code i am trying to fix:

```
import numpy as np

def nan_repl(x):
    k = np.where(np.isnan(x))
    x[k] = np.nanmean(x[:,k[1]],axis=0)

def pca(x,std = True, nlib = 0):
    if std:
        x_ = (x - np.mean(x,axis=0))/np.std(x,axis=0)
    else:
        x_ = x - np.mean(x, axis=0)
    n,m = np.shape(x)
    assert isinstance(x_,np.ndarray)
    mat = (1/(n-nlib))*x_.T@x_
    print(mat)
```

And the error is this:

```
"D:\Proiect Data Mining\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Proiect Data Mining/functii.py"   File "D:/Proiect Data Mining/functii.py", line 14
    mat = (1/(n-nlib))*x_.T@x_
                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to archive. What's the meaning of the underscore? Can you put parentheses at the right too so that the wanted expression is explicit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.matmul() to solve your error:

```
mat = (1/(n-nlib))*np.matmul(x_.T, x_)
```

You can refer to the documentation here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

I assumed the operation you're trying to perform was a matrix multiplication with the '@' operator, which is only supported in python 3.